# Should Jasmine 'expectationFailedOutput' messages describe what was expected, or what happened?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

Jasmine `expect` statements can produce worthless error messages like:

```
 Expected true to be false.
```

To address this, matchers allow you to add a clarifying message as a second argument, `expectationFailedOutput`:

```
toBe(expected: any, expectationFailOutput?: any): Promise<void>;
```

This allows you to write:

```
expect(await password.isDisplayed).toBe(true, "Password field should be visible");
expect(await password.isDisplayed).toBe(true, "Password field was not visible");
```

These will produce the following error messages, respectively:

```
Expected false to be true, 'Password field should be visible'.
Expected false to be true, 'Password field was not visible'.
```

Note, that these lines are the same except that in the first case, I described what the expect was testing for, and in the second, I describe what actually happened.

Obviously, I should choose one these conventions and use it consistently in my code base, but I can't find anything in the documentation about what the typical convention is. Should the message describe what we *expected* to happen, or should it describe what *did* happen?

If the Jasmine team doesn't have a convention for this, perhaps somebody who's worked on a lot of Jasmine projects knows what the typical convention is.

Comment: I do not know if that's helpful at all but we go for the first variant in our Java & JUnit-based tests. We also try to formulate our assert messages in a way the used convention is clearly communicated. For example, for the given example we would go with assert message 'Expected visible password field'.

Comment: Both points are helpful, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why it `should` be consistent and why it `obviously`. Some checks are easy to understand, some hard. When you feel that you need message - add it. Don't make it hard when it could be simple.

Comment: You didn't understand the question. It wasn't whether I should add a clarifying message. The question was: if I add a clarifying message, should it describe what I was expecting, or what actually happened. These are opposite of each other. e.g. if I say expect(x).toEqual(y), I could describe this as 'x should equal y', so the error messages says what I expect to happen, or I could say "x does not equal y", so the error message says what is actually happening. I need to use one or the other consistently, because otherwise the error messages are harder to interpret.